# Os.walk can't find xml file

Tags: python, xml

I am getting this error:

> source = open(source, "rb")
>     IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'XXX.xml'

I know the file exist in the directory but it won't find it. I believe I need to use the "dirs" from my for loop?

```
jdata = json.load(open(json_path))
if os.path.isdir(osWalkpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        print root, dirs, files
        for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
            for name in files:
                try:
                    dirs.remove('.svn')
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as fle:
                    content = fle.read()
                FindName(content, key, name, value) # <--- It complains here

def FindName(content, key, name, value):
    if name.endswith('.arxml') and re.search(Wordboundry(key), content):
        print "Name", key, "was found in", name, "\n"
        OverrideXML(key, value, name)
```

It seems like when I give the full path to where the file is it will find it, but when I just give a part of the path it will not find it.

Ex:

```
"C:\MyPath\XML\Dir1\ #Full path where the file exist
"C:\MyPath\XML\  #Not the full path (but file exist in the subdir "Dir1) and gives error since it can't find the XML
```

Some outputs:

> Name XYZ was found in XXX.xml <--- like wtf it finds the file

Comment: And what is the question? You exactly know what is wrong and what to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* to give the full path of the file, otherwise the operation system will search the file in the current directory.

If you want not to give the full path, you mus change your current working directory (`os.chdir`). But remember that you are changing your working directory and you won't be able to access files in the previews directory without changing it again.

I strongly recommend you to inform the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
xx = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, name))
FindName(content, key, xx, value)
```